# can we kill child process of any android application?why?

Tags: java, android, linux-kernel

i want to kill child process which accesses internet connection.
For example, Facebook android app, so can we kill facebook's child process by code? not application itself only child

Comment: A parent will get a signal SIGCHLD and thus may exit because of that.

Comment: we can't kill child process till we get superuser permission. we can only kill parent process.